# Prefix query on VARBINARY leveraging index

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have an index on a VARBINARY(200) column. How can I do a prefix query that leverages that index?

I tried `WHERE LEFT(column, 20) = @value` but that doesn't leverage the index.

I am using SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2):

One method might to use `between`.  Something like this:

```
where column >= left(val, 20) and column < left(val, 20) + ???
```

I'm not sure exactly what ??? should be.

Perhaps a better method is to use a computed column, but this assumes that you are always looking for 20 bytes:

```
alter table t add column_20 as (cast(column as varbinary(20));

create index idx_t_column20 on t(column_20);
```

Then equality should use the index:

```
where column_20 = @value
```

Comment: Maybe `column <= left(val, 19) + char(65536-1)`? Not sure this covers all edge cases.